# Struts 1 <display:table> don't sort

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts-1

Hello guys use Struts 1 with Hibernate and JSP. I have a problem ordering of the column of "display: table" that does not work. We place the following code:
FILE JSP:

```
<display:table name="listaPersone" id="row">
<display:column property="nome" title="Nome" sortable="true"/> 
<display:column property="cognome" title="Cognome" sortable="true"/> 
<display:column property="eta" title="Eta" sortable="true"/> 
<display:column property="sex" title="Sesso" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

Action:

```
List<Person> lista = service.listAll();
            request.setAttribute("listaPersone", lista);
            result = mapping.findForward("success");
```

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:
My class Person:

```
public class Person implements Serializable,Comparable<Person>{
...
@Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.getEta()-o.getEta();
    }
}
```

this is right or how can I implement ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following attributes :

> **defaultorder** : The default order for the sorted column. Valid values are "ascending" (default) or "descending" String
>
> **defaultsort** : The index of the column that will be used by default for sorting (starting from 1)
>
> **sort** : Use 'page' if you want to sort only visible records, or 'list' if you want to sort the full list, or 'external' if the data is sorted outside displaytag.

### Source

- [Display tag reference](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html)

Comment: Thanks! He tells me to sort by that column must implement the Comparable interface, simply estendendere only the interface or should I go also to create a method that sorts ?? Thanks!

Comment: @ZackNero : Its good to write your custom sort method. If you implement `Comparable` interface then `compareTo()` method must be overridden in your implemented class.

Comment: Excuse the beginner and would like to better understand how to implement the interface. I put my class with the CompareTo method, but I have doubts about that because vorreo ordered for each type of column ... Maybe I can post an example ??